# How to ensure that specific objects are instantiated by another object only?

Tags: php, design-patterns, registry

How can I ensure that an object will be instantiated only via another particular object?

For example, say I have a Registry object to store my Mappers.  When client code calls the `get()` method on the Registry, it lazy loads and returns the requested Mapper.  That's fine, except there is nothing to stop client code from creating a duplicate instance of the Mapper using the `new` operator.

The only option I can think of is that my Mappers require a Registry object as a parameter.  Are there other options?

What do you do?  Should I even bother about preventing this kind of duplication?

Comment: Maybe I didn't get your question, but why don't you declare Mapper as static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should not try to prevent people from creating instances themselves? If you don't trust yourself or your colleagues not to instantiate objects in places where they should not instantiate them, you have a problem.

If the mappers do not need a registry to function, you should not object it via the constructor. Passing it to some static method seems rather odd, and makes your code less flexible since you're using static. And how are you going to unit test the mappers, without writing some hacks to properly instantiate them via the registry you should not have need for in these tests? Good post on  that here: http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/0103_static_considered_harmful.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't protect from the `new` operator. What you could do though is that you have a `get()` method in your class to make your class/object singleton (or using a Registry as you do).

```
class clTest {
 private static $oInstance;

 public static function get() {
  if( !self::$oInstance ) {
   self::$oInstance = new clText;
  }

  return self::$oInstance;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to prevent outside instantiation you only need to declare __construct as private and then use a call to a static method to get an instance of the Mapper class. You can then pass in an instance of the registry class and only return a new instance if the parameter is an instance of the registry class.

```
class Mapper{
  private __construct(){}

  public static function getInstance($registry){
    if($registry instanceof Registry){
      return new Mapper();
    }
  }
}

$registry = new Registry();
$mapper = Mapper::getInstance($registry);
```